# connection to Java DB always fails

Tags: java, database, derby

The documentation for [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) says that it comes bundled with the JDK, and I have read that no special class loading is required in later Java versions (I have Java 8). However, trying to connect to it fails completely:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:testDB;create=true")
```

This throws a SQLException, with the SQL state being 08001 (connection failed).

I also tried explicitly loading the driver class, but it also throws an error:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");// ClassNotFoundException
```

The code below cannot even compile because the derby classes are not found:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
```

How do I connect to a database with Java DB?

Comment: well this is pretty obvious. add the jar to your project

Comment: It was only automatically in the runtime classpath with certain JDK versions, and certain Java vendors. And it was never in the **compile** classpath, you always have to explicitly add it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the "built-in" Java DB, you have to add the derby jar to your classpath manually. This is how I did it in Gradle:

```
testCompile files("$System.env.JAVA_HOME/db/lib/derby.jar")
```

I dislike this because it means that you are dependent on the local directory structure, as opposed to normal dependencies which are resolved by name and version number.

I had expected "Java DB" to be fully integrated into the standard library, but this is not the case. It is simply colocated with every JDK installation. As this has the additional drawback of generally being an outdated derby release, I will ignore Java DB and just use the latest derby version from maven central:

```
testCompile group: 'org.apache.derby', name: 'derby', version: '10.13.1.1'
```

Note also that the previously required `Class.forName(...)` statement still throws `ClassNotFoundException`; the statement is not required to make derby work.